# Why is my mysql database not updating (using flask/python)

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm currently trying to add a user to the database when they enter in a username and password. However, the database is not updating at all and all of the info that was in the database just stays the same. I've tested out the code and it does run but the mysql.connect().commit() is not committing the code to the database.

my flask file:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request, Response, json, redirect, url_for
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import re
from MyFunction import *
from get_tv_name import *

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="", static_url_path='')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'F34TF$($e34D';
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ""
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'accounts'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/register.html/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * from _accounts where Username='" + request.form['username'] + "' and Password='" + request.form['password'] + "'")
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        if data == None:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO _accounts VALUES (null,  '" + request.form['username'] + "', '" + request.form['password'] + "')")
            mysql.connect().commit
            redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            error = "it is complete"
return render_template('/register.html/', error=error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

my html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 centered">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"> <strong class="">Create an Account!</strong>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputFirstName3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="First Name" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputLastName3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Last Name" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{
      request.form.username }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                           <input type="password" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{
      request.form.password }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group last">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Create account</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should that be ".commit" or ".commit()"

Comment: I just re-tried it with both and .commit and .commit() are still working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason the database isn't updating is that you aren't committing the transaction. You create a connection with `mysql.conn()` and then get a cursor from it by adding `.cursor()`. When you go to commit your changes, you get a brand new connection by again calling `mysql.conn()`.

What you want to do is capture a reference to the connection so that it can be used later. You'll also want to use a parameterized query to avoid things like SQL injection attacks.

```
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()

data = cursor.fetchone()
if data is None:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO _accounts VALUES (null, %s, %s)", (request.form['username'], request.form['password']))
    conn.commit()
    redirect(url_for('index'))  # I'm guessing you want to put a return here.
else:
    error = "it is complete"    # snip
```

Lastly, when comparing to `None` you'll want to use the `is` operator rather than equality. [From PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

Comment: Been trying to figure this out for hours! Thank you!